# bazel build aot with cross tool failed in platform.h fatal error 'mutex' file not found

Tags: tensorflow, cross-compiling, aot

I am trying aot cross compiling with bazel.But failed in platform.h fatal error 'mutex' file not found.I can build with bazel without cross compile setting, and I can exec the binary in host.

My environment is below

- x86-64 ubuntu14.04
- target:arm-linux-gnueabihf
- tensorflow:Head of maste cd5f3b67fca88217776522182481b0c128db5af9
- bazel:0.5.4　installed by apt-get install

My test code is below.

```
#define EIGEN_USE_THREADS
#define EIGEN_USE_CUSTOM_THREAD_POOL

#include <iostream>
#include "third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"
#include "tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests/test_graph_tfmatmul.h" // generated

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Eigen::ThreadPool tp(2);  // Size the thread pool as appropriate.
  Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice device(&tp, tp.NumThreads());

  foo::bar::MatMulComp matmul;
  matmul.set_thread_pool(&device);

  // Set up args and run the computation.
  const float args[12] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
  std::copy(args + 0, args + 6, matmul.arg0_data());
  std::copy(args + 6, args + 12, matmul.arg1_data());
  matmul.Run();

  // Check result
  if (matmul.result0(0, 0) == 58) {
    std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Failed. Expected value 58 at 0,0. Got:"
              << matmul.result0(0, 0) << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I modified the some files to compile.

1. add cross compile setting to WORKSPACE file

   > new_local_repository(   name = "linaroLinuxGcc49Repo",   build_file =
   >   "compilers/linaro_linux_gcc_4.9.BUILD",   path =
   >   "compilers/gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf", )
2. add build setting in /tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests/BUILD

   > cc_binary(
   >       name = "my_binary",
   >       srcs = [
   >           "my_code.cc",  # include test_graph_tfmatmul.h to access the generated header
   >       ],
   >       deps = [
   >           ":test_graph_tfmatmul",  # link in the generated object file
   >           "//third_party/eigen3",
   >       ],
   >       linkopts = [
   >             "-lpthread",
   >       ] )

Below is the build command I did.

> bazel build --copt=-Wno-c++11-narrowing --cxxopt='-std=c++11'
>   //tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests:my_binary
>   --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain --crosstool_top=//tools/arm_compiler:toolchain --cpu=armeabi-v7a --verbose_failures

Finally I get the error below.

> (root) user-name@machine-name:repo
>   [master]$ bazel build --copt=-Wno-c++11-narrowing
>   --cxxopt='-std=c++11' //tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests:my_binary --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain --crosstool_top=//tools/arm_compiler:toolchain --cpu=armeabi-v7a --verbose_failures WARNING: /home/user-name/tensorflow/repo/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1772:1: in
>   includes attribute of cc_library rule
>   //tensorflow/core:framework_headers_lib: '../../external/nsync/public'
>   resolves to 'external/nsync/public' not below the relative path of its
>   package 'tensorflow/core'. This will be an error in the future. Since
>   this rule was created by the macro 'cc_header_only_library', the error
>   might have been caused by the macro implementation in
>   /home/user-name/tensorflow/repo/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl:1029:30
>   WARNING:
>   /home/user-name/tensorflow/repo/tensorflow/contrib/learn/BUILD:15:1:
>   in py_library rule //tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn: target
>   '//tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn' depends on deprecated target
>   '//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:exporter': No longer supported.
>   Switch to SavedModel immediately. WARNING:
>   /home/user-name/tensorflow/repo/tensorflow/contrib/learn/BUILD:15:1:
>   in py_library rule //tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn: target
>   '//tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn' depends on deprecated target
>   '//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:gc': No longer supported. Switch
>   to SavedModel immediately. INFO: Analysed target
>   //tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests:my_binary (0 packages loaded). INFO:
>   Found 1 target... ERROR:
>   /home/user-name/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user-name/6d2eb697f6f4dfadad89ea8a861fded5/external/nsync/BUILD:397:1:
>   C++ compilation of rule '@nsync//:nsync_cpp' failed (Exit 1): clang
>   failed: error executing command    (cd
>   /home/user-name/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user-name/6d2eb697f6f4dfadad89ea8a861fded5/execroot/org_tensorflow
>   && \   exec env - \
>       PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
>       PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/home/user-name/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.4.0/bin/python
>   \
>       PYTHON_LIB_PATH=/home/user-name/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.4.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages
>   \
>       TF_NEED_CUDA=0 \
>       TF_NEED_OPENCL=0 \   tools/arm_compiler/linaro_linux_gcc/clang_bin/clang -target
>   armv7a-arm-linux-gnueabif
>   '--sysroot=external/linaroLinuxGcc49Repo/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc'
>   '-mfloat-abi=hard' -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/clang/3.6/include
>   -isystem external/linaroLinuxGcc49Repo/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.4/include
>   -isystem external/linaroLinuxGcc49Repo/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include
>   -isystem external/linaroLinuxGcc49Repo/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.4/include-fixed
>   -isystem external/linaroLinuxGcc49Repo/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include
>   -isystem external/linaroLinuxGcc49Repo/include/c++/4.9.4 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -fPIE '-fdiagnostics-color=always' -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wno-c++11-narrowing -MD -MF bazel-out/clang_linux_armhf-py3-opt/bin/external/nsync/_objs/nsync_cpp/external/nsync/internal/sem_wait.d
>   -iquote external/nsync -iquote bazel-out/clang_linux_armhf-py3-opt/genfiles/external/nsync -iquote
>   external/bazel_tools -iquote
>   bazel-out/clang_linux_armhf-py3-opt/genfiles/external/bazel_tools
>   -isystem external/nsync/public -isystem bazel-out/clang_linux_armhf-py3-opt/genfiles/external/nsync/public
>   -isystem external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/gcc3 -x c++ '-std=c++11' -DNSYNC_ATOMIC_CPP11 -DNSYNC_USE_CPP11_TIMEPOINT -I./external/nsync//platform/c++11 -I./external/nsync//platform/gcc -I./external/nsync//platform/arm -I./external/nsync//public -I./external/nsync//internal -I./external/nsync//platform/posix '-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L' -pthread -no-canonical-prefixes
>   -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -c
>   external/nsync/internal/sem_wait.c -o
>   bazel-out/clang_linux_armhf-py3-opt/bin/external/nsync/_objs/nsync_cpp/external/nsync/internal/sem_wait.o)
>   warning: unknown warning option '-Wunused-but-set-parameter'; did you
>   mean '-Wunused-parameter'? [-Wunknown-warning-option] warning: unknown
>   warning option '-Wno-free-nonheap-object'; did you mean
>   '-Wno-sequence-point'? [-Wunknown-warning-option] In file included
>   from external/nsync/internal/sem_wait.c:16:
>   ./external/nsync//platform/c++11/platform.h:29:10: fatal error:
>   'mutex' file not found
>   #include 
>            ^ 2 warnings and 1 error generated. Target //tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests:my_binary failed to build INFO:
>   Elapsed time: 0.917s, Critical Path: 0.15s FAILED: Build did NOT
>   complete successfully

Error occures in "C++ compilation of rule '@nsync//:nsync_cpp' failed (Exit 1):" .

Befause of "./external/nsync//platform/c++11/platform.h:29:10: fatal error: 'mutex' file not found
#include 
"

The file mutex is exist in ./compilers/gcc-linaro-4.9-2016.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.9.4/mutex.

I think path above is setted in the build output line "-isystem external/linaroLinuxGcc49Repo/include/c++/4.9.4"

How could I set the path to mutex? for cross compiling nsync?

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake when I edit CROSSTOOL file.
If you know detail, please refer below.

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3836

thanks!